# Adding space at the end of a line in Gherkin

Tags: gherkin, cucumber-java

My question is:

I have a datatable with some values. and i want to the end of one of the values to have a whitespace.

eg.

```
| Name | Surname | Statement           |
| AO   | PO      | This is a statement |
```

i want to add a whitespace after the word statement. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your stepdefinitions (using `{string}`, `{word}` or the `^...$` notation) you can do

```
| Name | Surname | Statement              |
| AO   | PO      | "This is a statement " |
```

Or use the whitespace character

```
| Name | Surname | Statement              |
| AO   | PO      | This is a statement\s  |
```